# Phonegap.js not called second time

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am creating a WP7.1 Application with Phonegap. I have a html page in which I have added number of javascripts along with phonegap.js.
When for the first time the page is loaded, everything works fine.
But when i navigate back and come again to the same page, device ready is not called.
Also I cannot call other functions in other js too.

Why this is happening?
is there some error occurring in some js. How can i track it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Phonegap can be quite challenging because it often fails silently. Because your scripts appear to run the first time, it may not be a simple syntax error causing problems.  Try running the scripts on a desktop browser with a JS debug console available and you may see some error messages there.  Although Phonegap itself may not run, it is usually not too difficult to keep a compatibility layer with a desktop browser that will help you spot simple mistakes.

You can also look at using the remote Weinre debugger.  This gives you a debug console for your development device which may show error messages that the dev environment itself doesn't.  Try:-

http://debug.phonegap.com/

You state that you are including Phonegap.js, presumably you are using a current version such as Phonegap 1.9.0?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but the problem is still there. I am not able to get what causing it?